# Accessing passed in argument in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am new to assembly programming and am having issues passing and accessing a data list in a function. I am working though a pdf I downloaded from the www titled Programming Ground Up by Jonathan Bartlett. Anyway, I can create a data list but when I pass it to my function I can only get the first value' all of the rest seem to be garbage but they do seem consistent between executions. I have been trying to figure this out for a couple days and scoured the www looking for answers but haven't found any. So here I am.

The task is to push the data list onto the stack
call the function
pull the argument off the stack
grab an element off the argument
pass it back in eax

I am using GAS on x86 Linux

```
    data_list:  .long 7,6,5,4,3
    data_items: .long
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
    movl data_list, %eax
    pushl %eax
    call pass

    # move eax to ebx
    movl %eax, %ebx

    # set exit 
    movl $1, %eax

    # call kernel
    int $0x80

.type pass, @function
pass:
    # save off ebp
    pushl %ebp

    # move esp to ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    # get argument
    movl 8(%ebp), %ebx

    # move ebx to our variable
    movl %ebx, data_items

    # set edi to then index we want
    movl $4, %edi

    # get element from data and put it into our return value
    movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
done:
    # reset esp
    movl %ebp, %esp

    # pop ebp
    popl %ebp

    # return to caller
    ret
```

I am expecting it to return 3 but i get 116. This leads to be believe that it's only passing a copy of the first element in the data list as if edi is 0 I get the correct value.

Comment: `movl data_list, %eax` is passing the first value. You want to pass the address so use a `$` prefix, e.g. `movl $data_list, %eax`. That will of course give you a pointer you need to dereference so `movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax` is wrong and should instead be `movl (%ebx,%edi,4), %eax`

Comment: That did it, thank you so much. I knew I was missing something. I did try the $data_list in my testing but not the movl (%ebx,%edi,4)